# Callback instance conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I have the following callback in a polymer element that is only supposed to fire when data is received with a specific `dataid` value.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'widget-singlevalue',
    properties: {
        dataid: {
            type: String
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            value: 'Loading'
        },
        sparks: {
            type: Object,
            value: []
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        console.log(this.dataid);
        var self = this;
        registerCallback(this.dataid, function (data) {
            var y = data.data[0];
            var i = y[Object.keys(y)[0]];
            self.push('sparks', i);
            console.log(self.dataid + ": " + self.sparks);
            self.value = i;
        });
    }
});
```

Elements:

```
<widget-singlevalue name="Retrieves Per Minute" dataid="AvgRetPerMin"></widget-singlevalue>

<widget-singlevalue name="Total" dataid="Total"></widget-singlevalue>
```

The `value` seems to always be right, however when I look at the `sparks` arrays on each widget/element, they are mixed up.  Here is my current console output:

```
AvgRetPerMin: 63.81,63.81,14891940,14891940,57.67,57.67,14892034,14892034,57.33,57.33
Total: 63.81,14891940,14891940,57.67,57.67,14892034,14892034,57.33,57.33,14892034
```

Total.Sparks should only ever have values in the 14 million range, the other should be double digits with a decimal.

Comment: Cannot really help you with the amount of information present in the question. But some mistakes that i found in your code are `sparks` type is `Object` but value an `Array`. So change `sparks` type to `Array` and for both arrays and objects use function to return value( Polymer recommendation) `value:function(){return []}`

Comment: Wow, so fixing those two things actually seems to have fixed the issue.  Guess you didn't need more info after all! :)

Can you post as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes that that are present in your code are

- `sparks` `type` is `Object` but `value` an `Array`. So change `sparks` type to `Array`
- And for both arrays and objects use function to return value. As per Polymer recommendation it always use function to return value for Object and Arrays. The reason behind this is so that each instance of the element has its own copy of the Object/Array

  ```
  value:function(){
          return []
        }
  ```